# Input type number in HelperForm PrestaShop

Tags: overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am unable to set input type number in HelperForm PrestaShop. 
Only text and password types are working. When set to number type, the input box disappears.

```
$fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
    'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
    ),
    'input' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'number',
            'label' => $this->l('Number Input'),
            'name' => 'NumberInput',
            'required' => true
        )
    ),
    'submit' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Save'),
        'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
    )
);
```

Comment: Which version of prestashop are you using?

Comment: @sarcom version 1.7.0.4

Comment: Sorry, no number, only text and password, you have to extend the form.tpl and add the number type, if you are developing a module

Answer (score 8):

You can set the type as follows:

```
$fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
    'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
    ),
    'input' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'html',
            'label' => $this->l('Number Input'),
            'name' => 'NumberInput',
            'required' => true,
            'html_content' => '<input type="number" name="NumberInput">'
        )
    ),
    'submit' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Save'),
        'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
    )
);
```

You can use for example`min="1" max="5"`in the input.

According to the form.tpl in admin theme, this should work.

Comment: Its working but the value I am getting from the DB is not showing in that. Using the same code to set the value as type text. `$helper->fields_value['NumberInput'] = Configuration::get('NumberInput');` @sadlyblue

Comment: Load the object before the fields_form. Then add the value to the input to get: <input type="number" name="NumberInput" value="123">

Answer (score 3):

There is no `number` type in PrestaShop helper forms, that is the only reason the input box disappears when you put type as `number`.

What you can do to achieve this is to create a simple input field and add help text or tooltip to indicate that this field only accepts numeric values. Following code can be used to add help text or tooltip to the HelperForm.

```
array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Custom Label',
                    'required' => true,
                    'hint' => 'Custom Tool Tip',
                    'desc' => 'Custom Help Text'
)
```

In the validation part, you can use the put the validation for numbers only and return an error if the value entered is not as expected.

Comment: where should i do the validation part? @Knowband